# Is this MD5 method of comparing an external database safe?

Tags: mysql, security, md5

I have an (opt-in) email-list, which is pretty successful. One bigger company has shown an interest and wants to buy my list, which is fine. But to check if we have any overlap, the company asks me if I can MD5(email@address.com) from within MYSQL and give them the hashed list so they can compare for overlap.

Isn't this the ideal situation for a collision attack? I assume every email you MD5 in Mysql has no decryption key, so if they find a match, they could reverse engineer my email list.

Comment: You can always reverse the question and have them provide the encrypted list.  If you wanted to keep things relatively safe, then do the comparison on, say, a 1% random sample.  That should be good enough for significant overlap.

Comment: A collision attack would be finding a string which hashes the same as one the addresses you give them. What use would that be? They're interested in the addresses, not in faking the thing.

Comment: Suppose example@email.com is present in my database and in theirs. I assume the MD5 string is the same right? We will have hunderds of overlapping email adresses, because they own millions of adresses. So they could reverse engineer my email list?

Comment: Yes, or they could perform a dictionary attack on it. Supplying an MD5 of the list is basically nonsense. I can understand why they would want to do this, but it is really not an option. The only option I see if to have a trusted 3rd party, e.g. a notary, and have them compare the mail addresses or hashes. Collision attacks are not the problem, nor is the hash function in this case. BTW, not a programming question, try [security.se] instead.